# When is it safe to delete an Image source file in .Net?

Tags: .net, image, gdi+

When using the code below I sometimes get the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save". I've started to believe that it's because I delete the source image before saving the newly created image. Is that the case? When is it really safe to delete a source Image file then?

The sub class:

```
thumbnailImage = GetThumb();
thumbnailImage.Save(fullDestinationFilename);
```

The base class:

```
public virtual Image GetThumb() {
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(sourceFile)) {
        thumbImage = Crop(image, BrowserWidth, BrowserHeight));
    }
    File.Delete(sourceFile);
    return thumbImage;
}

private static Image Crop(Image image, int width, int height) { 
    var croppedImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage)){
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
       return croppedImage;
   }
```

}

Comment: If you load an Image/Bitmap from file, you cannot delete that instance's source. Not sure about the exact detail, but it is a known 'quirk'.

Comment: I realized I could test to not delete the source file at all, so I did that but the Exception is still thrown sometimes. I'm clueless at the moment.

Comment: It is not your code.  Deleting files can be tricky, there might be another process that's looking at the file.  A possible workaround is to rename the file before deleting it.  If the delete fails then you can stomp it next time by deleting the renamed file first.

Comment: The deletion of the file isn't the problem, it's the saving of the new image created from the original image (sourceFile).

Comment: Might it be the Crop method? Is it bad to dispose the graphics object and then return the image?

Comment: I don't think so. The reverse (using the graphics object after the image has been disposed) would be a problem. All of this looks fine to me. I think you should be looking at the Save call; is it possible that your destination filename cannot be created or is an image format that doesn't support the 32-bit RGBA format?

Comment: Seems like the problem was that I did not dispose the image after writing it to the http response stream. I think this made the image locked and the next request tried to overwrite the locked image which resulted in an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it to work now. The problem didn't lie in the code I showed you. After saving the thumbnail to file I wrote it to the http response stream and DID NOT DISPOSE the thumbnail image. When another request that resulted in a save on that file came in it couldn't overwrite the image file because it was still locked from the last request.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like this

```
public virtual Image GetThumb() {
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(sourceFile)) {
        thumbImage = Crop(image, BrowserWidth, BrowserHeight));
    }
    if(thumbImage != null)
    {     
      File.Delete(sourceFile);
    }
    return thumbImage;
}
```

Also I think it is better if you use **try catch** statement.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a question/guess. One that is wrong, btw.